# Css nesting and hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I have following HTML

```
<li>
    <div>
         <div>
          ..
          ...
          <span class="A">text</span>
         </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

How do I change the color of text when I hover over the li element using CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
li:hover span.A {
   color: red;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/x9WNc/)

Comment: @Adrift That was typo :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
li:hover span.A {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
li:hover .A
{
    color: red;
}
```

As show here:
http://jsfiddle.net/rZCwr/